# Modelling with a delay

Tags: multiple-regression, mixed-model, multivariate-analysis

Im just at the stage of looking at my data and seeing how I can model it.  My data is on the cooling effect of tree shade given various measured tree variables but to make the model useful I also need to include solar radiation, as this is obviously the main driver of floor temperatures and thus greatly influences cooling.  The problem is that there is a delay in the system i.e peak cooling in the tree shade during the day occurs an hour or two after peak solar radiation due to the thermal properties of floor materials.

So my multiple regression model will look like:

cooling degree = radiation + tree volume + gapfraction + leafareaindex + leafbrightness

I have radiation data for all of my tree shade measuring datapoints but how can I include it in the model when this delay exists?

Is it simply a matter of calculating what the delay is e.g. by analysing when peak radiation is in comparison to peak cooling and adjusting the radiation data by this time factor? i.e. using the radiation data from earlier in the day which corresponds to roughly the same point on the diurnal trend curve for cooling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Is it simply a matter of calculating what the delay is e.g. by analysing when peak radiation is in comparison to peak cooling and adjusting the radiation data by this time factor? "    Essentially Yes !

But it appears that you are locking in the temporal response. With time series effects you often have dynamic structure where particular input can have an effect on Y for more than 1 period. Also be aware that there may be anomalous data points that require special handling.

You might want to read http://www.autobox.com/pdfs/regvsbox-old.pdf and http://docplayer.net/12080848-Outliers-level-shifts-and-variance-changes-in-time-series.html and http://faculty.chicagobooth.edu/ruey.tsay/teaching/uts/lec10-08.pdf as time series brings special opportunities.